# Using INDEX and MATCH in Excel with slightly different spellings

Tags: excel, merge, dataset

**OBJECTIVE:** I'm trying to merge two Excel datasets. They both contain information on a set of companies, with some commonalities and some differences with respect to the infomation they contain. Dataset 1 contains addresses for each of the companies' branches, whereas dataset 2 has information on the number of employees in each branch. In both datasets, there are columns for company name, region, and branch name. I'd like the number of employees in each branch to be included in dataset 1.

**MY SOLUTION:** I've used `=INDEX{I3:L12, MATCH[1, (A3=I3:I12)*(C3=J3:J12)(D3=K3:K12),0],4}` to find the matching company, region, and branch and then copy over the corresponding # of employees. this works for most of the data.

**THE PROBLEM:** Some companies are spelt differently: in dataset 1, you might find "Tremblay-Marois Inc" whereas in dataset 2, you find "Tremblay-Marois Incorporated". This causes the `#N/A` error. To be noted: Dataset 2 contains some companies that are not present in dataset 1, so a simply copy-paste is not possible; the datasets are both extremely large, so simply manually changing names is not an option; and I tried using `VLOOKUP` for approximate matches, but it is TOO inexact.

Do you have any ideas for how I could have the sheet recognize these slightly differently spelt companies?

Comment: Perhaps the [Fuzzy Lookup Add-In](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011) from MSFT.

Comment: For the sake of testing, have you tried adjusting the third argument of `match` for *similar* not *exact* matches?  that sometimes resolves these issues.  Note that for this to work the majority of the text has to be similar, e.g., not "Abe Lincoln" versus "Lincoln, Abe" but "Abe Lincoln" versus "Abe Lincoln Jr"...